# Is it possible to load redshift using bulk copy command using python boto package. I do not see a way to do this

Tags: boto, amazon-redshift

Is it possible to load redshift using bulk copy command using python boto package.  I do not see a way to do this.  It seems a JDBC client is necessary.

Comment: COPY is a SQL command sent over JDBS/ODBS connection.

Comment: If you'are using python, you'll need a postgreSQL binder like psycopg2 to connect to redshift and then run a "copy" command.

Answer (score 0):

No, `boto` is not used to load data into Amazon Redshift.

Data can be loaded into **Amazon Redshift** from:

- **Amazon S3:** Great for bulk, parallel loads. Can load compressed data.
- **Remote hosts:** Copies remote files to Amazon S3 for loading.
- **Amazon DynamoDB:** Load data directly from a DynamoDB table.
- **Via SQL queries** such as INSERT and UPDATE (but these are less efficient).

The python `boto` package provides access to AWS APIs. These can be used with Redshift to create, snapshot, reboot, describe and resize clusters (plus other commands).

However, the process to load data into Redshift (eg via Amazon S3) is done with the `COPY` command that is called via the normal ODBC or JDBC connection -- just like calling a `SELECT` command:

```
copy <table_name>
from 's3://<bucket_name>/<object_prefix>'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<access-key-id>;aws_secret_access_key=<secret-access-key>';
```

You could, however, use a standard Python JDBC library to connect to Redshift and execute the COPY command to bulk load data.

See also:

- [Loading Data from an Amazon DynamoDB Table](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Loading-data-from-dynamodb.html)
- [Redshift API reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html)